# pygame move rectangle stays at top but move_ip moves

Tags: python, pygame

when i change move_ip() to move() in pygame the rectangle stays at the top left
there are no errors
it just opens the pygame window with the rectangle at the top left
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcdOR.png)

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(charcolor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  # Get rect of some size as 'image'.
        self.rect.move(50,400)
        self.velocity = [10, 0]

        def update():
            self.rect.move_ip(*self.velocity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`move_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) changes the position of the object itself, [`move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) returns a new object with a different position, but does not change the object itself.
Hence `self.rect.move(50,400)` does nothing at all, because the return value goes nowhere.

The statement

```py
self.rect.move_ip(50,400)
```

can be replaced by

```py
self.rect = self.rect.move(50,400)
```